# No event is received after clicking the UIButton in custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom cell which subclasses from UITableViewCell. I added a click event for the button inside my custom cell, but nothing happens after clicking the button.

My code basically looks like following:

MyCustomCell.h:

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *thumbnailButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
// bla bla...
@end
```

MyTableViewController.h:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
// bla bla...
- (void)thumbnailButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender;
// bla bla...
@end
```

MyTableViewController.m:

```
#import "MyTableViewController.h"
#import "MyCustomCell.h"

// bla bla...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";
    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [cell.thumbnailButton addTarget:self 
                             action:@selector(thumbnailButtonClicked:)  
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.thumbnailButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}

- (void)thumbnailButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"[%d] Button Clicked!", sender.tag);
}
```

The coordination of the thumbnailButton above is (7, 6, 100, 66) which does not exceed its parent's frame.

Could anyone kindly tell me how to solve the problem? I have struggled with this for a while...

Comment: Maybe because you set userInteractionEnabled to NO for the contentView?

Comment: 1) Is your tableView delegate set correctly? Is the rest of the code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath called? 2) Perhaps you've got  cancelsTouchesInView = NO set for the tableView cell?

Comment: the code (as written) will continuously add actions to the cell's thumbnail button each time the cell is re-used. Also, check to see if `cell.thumbnailButton` is `nil`.  It's possible you didn't wire up the views in your nib.

Comment: `[cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` the button is a subview so taps will not get passed

Comment: in custom cell's .m file what you've written for creating button...?

Comment: @rdelmar the result is still the same even after removed.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments:D. I have found why it happened..., because I added an overlay view in my viewDidLoad...